# Android - Branch.io Deep linking not working in chrome

Tags: branch.io

I have integrated the branch.io SDK with my android app. I created the deep link URL with custom URI scheme(drbond://) in the dashboard. When clicking the deep link from a mobile browser it takes me to the app(If installed). But in chrome, it doesn't. I tried with Opera, Mozilla, and other default browsers are working fine. Please help me to deep linking working in chrome.

FYI,
My activity intent filter,

```
<intent-filter>
               <data android:scheme="drbond"  android:host="open" />
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: Are you entering the URL directly into the Chrome address bar, or opening it by clicking a link on another page?

Comment: Hi Alex Bauer. I have clicked the link from Gmail app. The issue was fixed by the branch.io support team. https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/issues/237

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop on this for anyone coming upon this ticket, the issue reported was due to the package name in the Android Manifest.xml file being set to an incorrect value. The package name in the manifest should match the package name configured for the Java project.